# Is there a way to get a quick preview/list of live templates in PHPStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have a lot of user defined live templates, but I don't use them quite often enough that I always remember what they are.

Is there a shortcut or hotkey to bring up a quick list without opening up settings and digging through the ones I've defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Invoke `Code | Insert Live Template` (<kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd>) to bring the list of all applicable in current context live templates (or just use code completion popup if they are listed there)
2. Select desired live template
3. Invoke `View | Quick Documentation` via shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl + Q</kbd>)

Now you should see both: list of live template + template body.

[image]

Comment: hi, that is nice, but what about the postfix tempaltes or similar? like `some code.if + TAB` or  `lorem +TAB` etc?

Comment: @Asped 1) There is no preview for Postfix templates. Possibly because  they are all hard coded and you cannot modify them. 2) Emmet (`lorem` is a specific Emmet case) has preview ability (no extra key-presses required AFAIK). Traditional live templates (most of the standard Emmet abbreviation expanding is done this way) can be previewed in a same way .

Comment: thanks for the info.. I thought these all are live templates